# Passing a route parameter to custom Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I've made a custom AuthorizeAttribute responsible of checking whether or not the user has access to a given resource. In order to make it generic, I need two variables passed into the attribute:

1. The requested Resource type
2. The requested Resource ID

I can easily tell the attribute which resource type was requested, but how to pass the requested ID into the attribute? Here is my code, with only the last variable missing (marked with a `?`):

```
[System.Web.Http.Authorize]
[System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/accounts")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    [AuthorizeIsOwnResource(ResourcesType = ResourcesTypes.Account, ResourceId = ?)]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("test/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Test(string id)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? I guess I could remove the attribute parameters all together, and decifer the requested resource type and ID from the `HttpContextBase` in the `AuthorizeCore`; but is it my only option?

Comment: You have the answer. I think the best solution is to access controller and action names from HttpContextBase. It's cleaner, easier to implement and less error prone.

Comment: After pondering a bit on the issue, I think you're absolutely right. I think I might even be able to extract the RouteData from the HttpContextBase. I will post a solution after I test it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright. Based on Douglas Gandini's comment, I decided that the best way is probably to leave it up to the Attribute to decide which ID was requested. Here is my working custom attribute:

```
public class AuthorizeIsOwnResourceAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public ResourcesTypes ResourcesType { get; set; }

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        var claimsIdentity = httpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var routeData = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.RouteData;

        switch (ResourcesType)
        {
            case ResourcesTypes.Account:
                return AuthorizeAccount(routeData, claimsIdentity);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool AuthorizeAccount(IHttpRouteData routedata, ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
    {

        var id = routedata.Values["id"].ToString();
        var accountClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "Resource-" + ResourcesTypes.Account);
        if (accountClaim == null || accountClaim.Value != id)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

In short: I get the requested ID from `actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.RouteData;` directly in my Attribute

Answer (score 0):

You could override the ActionDescriptor in the code for your AuthorizationContext:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext class using
    //     the specified controller context and action descriptor.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   controllerContext:
    //     The context in which the result is executed. The context information includes
    //     the controller, HTTP content, request context, and route data.
    //
    //   actionDescriptor:
    //     An object that provides information about an action method, such as its name,
    //     controller, parameters, attributes, and filters.
    public AuthorizationContext(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor);


    // Summary:
    //     Provides information about the action method that is marked by the System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
    //     attribute, such as its name, controller, parameters, attributes, and filters.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The action descriptor for the action method that is marked by the System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
    //     attribute.
    public virtual ActionDescriptor ActionDescriptor { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the result that is returned by an action method.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The result that is returned by an action method.
    public ActionResult Result { get; set; }
```